# How to fix DeploymentException: Failure while processing glassfish-resources.xml(s) in the archive

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, netbeans-8

I get the following exception when I deploy my app.

> DeploymentException: Failure while processing glassfish-resources.xml(s) in the archive

The path appears as if something was parsed incorrectly:

> HSE_MS-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jarMETA-INF\glassfish-resources.xml

I think that it should be :

> HSE_MS-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\META-INF\glassfish-resources.xml